# keypress event in autocomplete jquery ui

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I want to show the value of the autocomplete suggesion on textbox only when the user is selecting the suggession. I tried

```
$("#trainerNameAutoComplete").autocomplete({
    source:"serverpage.php?id="+1,
    minLength:1,
    focus: function( event, ui ){
        $("#trainerNameAutoComplete").val('');
    },
    keypress: function(event,ui){
        if ((event.which == 38||event.Keycode ==38) || (event.which == 40||event.Keycode ==40)) {
            console.log("key down");
            $("#trainerNameAutoComplete").val('');
        }
    },
    select:function(event,ui){
        somefunction();
    }
});
```

but the value is cleared in textbox when I hover the mouse over the suggestion but not when I press up and down arrow keys.

Answer (score 1):

```
 keydown: function(event,ui){
        event.preventDefault();
        if (event.Keycode ==38||event.Keycode ==40) {
            console.log("key down");
            $("#trainerNameAutoComplete").val('');
        }
    },
```

try this..instead of your keypress event